# Apache flink - Early firing window implementation issue - duplicate elements received

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am having quite hard time to understand flink windowing principals and would be very pleased if you could point me in the right direction.

My purpose is to count the number of recurring events for a time interval and generate alert events if the number of recurring events is greater than a threshold.

As I understand, windowing is a perfect match for this scenario.

Additional requirement is to generate an early alert if  recurring events count in a window is 2 (i.e. alert should be generated without waiting window end).

I thought that an alert event generating process window function can be used to aggregate windowed events and a custom trigger can be used to emit early results from the window based on the recurring events count (before the watermark reaches the window’s end timestamp).

I am using event-time semantics and having problems/questions for the custom trigger .

You can find the actual implementation in the gist: https://gist.github.com/simpleusr/7c56d4384f6fc9f0a61860a680bb5f36

I am using keyed state to keep track of element count in the window `encounteredElementsCountState`

Upon receiving first element I register `EventTimeTimer` to the window end. This is supposed to trigger `FIRE_AND_PURGE` for window closing and working as expected.

If the count exceeds threshold , I try to trigger early fire. This also seems to be successful, `processwindow` function is called immediately after this firing.

The problem is, I had to insert below check to the code without understanding the reason. Because the previously collected elements were again supplied to `onElement` method:

```
if (ctx.getCurrentWatermark() < 0) {
            logger.debug(String.format("onElement processing skipped for eventId : %s for watermark: %s ", element.getEventId(), ctx.getCurrentWatermark()));
            return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
        }
```

I could not figure out  the reason. What I see is that when this happens the watermark value is `(ctx.getCurrentWatermark()) Long.MIN_VALUE` (that leaded to the above check). How can this happen?

This check seems to avoid duplicate early event generation, but I do not know why this happens and is this workaround is appropriate.

Could you please advice why the same elements are processed twice in the window?

Another question is about the keyed state usage. Does this implementation leaks any state after window is disposed? I am trying to clear all used states in clear method of the trigger but would that be enough?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Each task has currentWatermark initialized to Long.MIN_VALUE, and this remains the local value of currentWatermark until larger watermarks have arrived from all of that task's input streams. Hopefully knowing that will help you better understand what's going on.

For what it's worth, often it's more straightforward to implement this kind of logic with a ProcessFunction than with the Window API.

Comment: Hi David, actually process function seemed like a low level processing operation to me(i.e. it seemed harder to maintain window boundaries without leaking state).

Comment: Also I later discovered from book "Stream Processing with Apache Flink" triggers are a natural fit for early firing.
(This is from chapter 6 of the boook:"A custom trigger can also be used to compute and emit early results from an event-time window, before the watermark reaches the window’s end timestamp").
As for your comment, watermark values > Long.MIN_VALUE already arrives to the window what I could not figure out is why are they reevaluated . 
I do not know if it is related but  watermark = Long.MIN_VALUE is the behavior I observe when such duplication occurs.